# Authentication is not working for our application running in MS Teams on iOS devices

Tags: keycloak, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We open authentication popup via @microsoft/teams-js authentication.authenticate, so it doesn’t run in the iframe. This correctly opens a popup on all platforms where user is able to authenticate with credentials or by using one of the Identity Providers we offer. We use Keycloak for identity management and it is clear that session is established and working within the authentication popup. This is further confirmed by the fact, that if the popup is closed and opened again, there is no need to enter credentials again, our keycloak backend is aware of active valid session. The problem is handing over the session to our application running inside MS Teams tab. Keycloak is using cookies to store current token, but thanks to ITP on iOS these cookies are not reachable in our application context, that is running inside MS Teams tab. The result is that our application inside MS Teams behaves as if user is not authenticated. This problem is present only on iOS devices, inside MS Teams app.

We have tried changing cookie settings including the samesite:none; secure; but without effect. We have tried storing the token and refresh token in the local storage, but our application running inside MS Teams tab cannot pick them up. We have tried code flow with PKCE, but it seems that client running inside MS Teams tab is under restrictions that prevent it from working. It's also complicated to debug as it's an app running inside an app running on iOS.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you please provide any repro steps or sample reference, so that we can try once from our end?

Comment: Hello @ivan - Could you please share any test credentials of your deployed app via email "microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com" to test your application from our end?